# Proof of one inequality $a+b+c\leq\frac{a^3}{bc}+\frac{b^3}{ca}+\frac{c^3}{ab}$

Tags: inequality, fractions, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, holder-inequality

How to prove this for positive real numbers?
$$a+b+c\leq\frac{a^3}{bc}+\frac{b^3}{ca}+\frac{c^3}{ab}$$

I tried AM-GM, CS inequality but all failed.

Comment: I hope it is given that $a,b,c \gt 0$.

Comment: Why somebody downvote?

Comment: Does $a$, $b$, $c$ are arbitrary real numbers? Or they are positive numbers?

Comment: @Lion Non zero reals.

Comment: Do you have try the method of extreme value of multivariable function?

Comment: @Lion You mean method of Lagrangian multiplier?

Comment: Yes. But there is no constrain in this case. So I think you can get the extreme value by compute derivative.

Comment: Remark that $a=-2$, $b=1$ and $c=1$ gives $-2+1+1=0 \le -8/1-1/2-1/2=-9$ which is wrong. So what is the domain of $a$,$b$ and $c$?

Comment: @Lion That's another way. I'd like to solve it using elementary inequalities.

Comment: @user37238 The original question doesn't mention it. So maybe it should be all positive.

Comment: Ok. I just want to say that a general method for inequality problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality twice:

$a^4 + b^4 +c^4 \geq a^2b^2 +b^2c^2 +c^2a^2 \geq ab^2c +ba^2c +ac^2b = abc(a+b+c)$

Comment: Substitute $a,b,c$ in $a^2 + b^2 +c^2 \geq ab +bc +ca$ with $ab,bc,ca$ respectively.

Comment: If $abc<0$ then you get the reverse inequality, right?

Comment: $a^2 + b^2 +c^2-ab-bc-ca = 1/2((a-b)^2 +(b-c)^2 +(c-a)^2) \geq 0$ so it holds for all $a,b,c$

Comment: Please try $a=-2$, $b=1$ and $c=1$.

Comment: @user129017, when you divide both sides by $abc$, then the inequality gets reversed when $abc \lt 0$.

Answer (score 7):

I have come up with an answer with myself. Using CS inequality
$$(a^4+b^4+c^4)(1+1+1)\geq(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2$$
$$(a^2+b^2+c^2)(1+1+1)\geq(a+b+c)^2$$
Hence we have
$$a^4+b^4+c^4\geq\frac{(a+b+c)^4}{27}=(a+b+c)\left(\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)^3\geq abc(a+b+c)$$

Comment: Your answer is invalid. $$\left(\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)\ge abc$$ does _not_ hold for all $a,b,c\in\mathbb R$. Mean inequalities are only used for positive numbers (except for $\frac{a+b}{2}\ge \sqrt{ab}$).

If you still don't believe me, take, e.g., $a=-1$, $b=-1$ and $c=1$.

Answer (score 7):

Here other two answers used Cauchy-Scwartz Inequality. I am giving a simple $AM\ge GM$ inequality proof.

You asked, $$\frac{a^3}{bc}+\frac{b^3}{ca}+\frac{c^3}{ab}\ge a+b+c\\\implies a^4+b^4+c^4\ge a^2bc+b^2ca+c^2ab$$

Now, from, $AM\ge GM$, we have $$\frac {a^4+
a^4+b^4+c^4}4\ge \left(a^4\cdot a^4\cdot b^4\cdot c^4\right)^{1/4}=a^2bc\tag 1$$

Similarly, $$\frac {a^4+
b^4+b^4+c^4}4\ge \left(a^4\cdot b^4\cdot b^4\cdot c^4\right)^{1/4}=ab^2c\tag 2$$ and also, $$\frac {a^4+
b^4+c^4+c^4}4\ge \left(a^4\cdot b^4\cdot c^4\cdot c^4\right)^{1/4}=abc^2\tag 3$$

Now, summing up $(1),(2),(3)$, we have, $a^4+b^4+c^4\ge a^2bc+b^2ca+c^2ab$, that is $$\frac{a^3}{bc}+\frac{b^3}{ca}+\frac{c^3}{ab}\ge a+b+c$$

Answer (score 5):

By Holder 
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^3}{bc}\geq\frac{(a+b+c)^3}{3(ab+ac+bc)}=\frac{(a+b+c)\cdot(a+b+c)^2}{3(ab+ac+bc)}\geq a+b+c$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way.

By Rearrangement 
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a^3}{bc}-a\right)=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{bc}(a^2-bc)\geq\frac{1}{3}\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{bc}\sum_{cyc}(a^2-bc)=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{bc}\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2\geq0.$$