# Is my Proof for the following problem correct? Prove that $a+b+c\leq\frac{a^3}{bc}+\frac{b^3}{ac}+\frac{c^3}{ab}$

Tags: inequality, problem-solving

If $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers prove that $$a+b+c\leq\frac{a^3}{bc}+\frac{b^3}{ac}+\frac{c^3}{ab}$$

I state the following:

Multiplying both sides by $abc$ yields $$(abc)(a+b+c)?{a^4+b^4+c^4}$$

By AM-GM for $abc$ we have $$abc\leq\left(\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)^3\Rightarrow\left(\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)^3(a+b+c)?{a^4+b^4+c^4}$$

This can be rewritten as the following:

$$\left(\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)^4\leq\frac{a^4+b^4+c^4}{3}$$

which holds due to the power mean inequality.

I was also thinking that it may be proven by a double application of the Chebyshev inequality as well

To begin, hold that ${a}\ge{b}\ge{c}$ observe that $$\left[\begin{matrix} a^3 & b^3 & c^3 \\ \frac{1}{a} & \frac{1}{b} &  \frac{1}{c}\end{matrix}\right]=a^2+b^2+c^2\leq\left[\begin{matrix} a^3 & b^3 & c^3 \\ \frac{1}{b} & \frac{1}{c} & \frac{1}{a}\end{matrix}\right]=\frac{a^3}{b}+\frac{b^3}{c}+\frac{c^3}{a}$$

Thus we can hold confidently even if we assume equality that $$\left[\begin{matrix} {a^2} & {b^2} & c^2 \\ \frac{1}{a} & \frac{1}{b} &  \frac{1}{c}\end{matrix}\right]=a+b+c\leq\left[\begin{matrix} \frac{a^3} 
 {b} & \frac{b^3}{c} & \frac{a^3}{a} \\ \frac{1}{c} & \frac{1}{a} & \frac{1}{b}\end{matrix}\right]=\frac{a^3}{bc}+\frac{b^3}{ac}+\frac{c^3}{ab}$$

Please provide feedback if you can.

Comment: Some of your conclusions are in the wrong direction: You *assume* what you are trying to prove, and conclude something which is correct. – See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/679544/42969 for some correct proofs of this inequality.

Comment: @MartinR I see, so if I had started from the power mean inequality and worked in the reverse order of what I did would it then be valid? Feel sorta dumb looking at it now. Or perhaps could i have just used the ? convention instead of assuming inequality from the beginning; I have seen textbooks use this convention.

Comment: I have no idea what the “? convention” is.

Comment: @MartinR I edited it in; it's essentially short hand for assume both cases that A<B and B<A, so once you find the one that gives way to a contradiction the latter is implied. For instance (x+y)^2?2xy becomes x^2+y^2?0; the obvious implication is the sign is >.

Comment: $\frac{a^3}{bc}+\frac{b^3}{ac}+\frac{c^3}{ab}\geq3\sqrt[15]{\frac{a^{15}+b^{15}+c^{15}}{3}}$ is also true for any positive variables. $\frac{a^3}{bc}+\frac{b^3}{ac}+\frac{c^3}{ab}\geq3\sqrt[16]{\frac{a^{16}+b^{16}+c^{16}}{3}}$ is wrong already.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is correct, but the proof is a bit confusing because it is not always clear if you *assume* the desired inequality or not. I would write it as follows:

Using the AM-GM inequality $(1)$ and the power-mean inequality $(2)$ we have
$$ 
abc(a+b+c)\underset{(1)}{\leq}(a+b+c)\left(\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)^3 = 3\left(\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)^4 \underset{(2)}{\leq} a^4 + b^4 + c^4
$$
and dividing by $abc$ gives
$$
a+b+c\leq\frac{a^3}{bc}+\frac{b^3}{ac}+\frac{c^3}{ab} \, .
$$

Comment: Thank you for the response I realize I sort of wrote it in reverse and should have presented it in the order of assumed inequality to implied inequality despite deriving it in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 0):

Using the inequality $$x^2+y^2+z^2\geq xy+yz+zx$$ twice we get
$$a^4+b^4+c^4\geq (ab)^2+(bc)^2+(ca)^2\geq abbc+abca+bcca=a^2bc+ab^2c+abc^2=abc(a+b+c)$$